# Search and replace special characters (å,ä,ö) for image attachments only in database

Tags: database, customization, characters

I need to replace the special characters å,ä,ö (with a or o) in my WP database for all image attachments. How can I apply this search and replace only to affect these links?

Edit: Solved

Comment: Where exactly in attachments?

Comment: I mean all the image links in the database that are attached to posts (under the wp_postmeta table).

Comment: This is a **PHP/SQL** question, **not** a *WordPress-specific* question. Per the WPSE FAQ, questions are not inherently on-topic merely because they take place in the *context* of WordPress.

Comment: Also: post your solution as an **answer**, rather than as an **edit** to your question.

Comment: Ok! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Solved -

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(meta_value, 'å', 'a') , 'ä', 'a') , 'ö', 'o')
WHERE LOWER(RIGHT(meta_value, 5)) = '.jpeg'
   OR LOWER(RIGHT(meta_value, 4)) IN ('.jpg', '.gif', '.png')
```

Comment: Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Just do this with your string:

```
$yourString = preg_replace ( '/å/' , 'a' , $yourString )
$yourString = preg_replace ( '/ä/' , 'a' , $yourString )
$yourString = preg_replace ( '/ö/' , 'o' , $yourString )
```

If you just want to do it with an SQL sentence, then you can try this :

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(StringColumn, 'å', 'a') , 'ä', 'a') , 'ö', 'o')
```

And you can use it in a SELECT, UPDATE, ... sentences, like this:

```
UPDATE MyTable

SET StringColumn = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(StringColumn, 'å', 'a') , 'ä', 'a') , 'ö', 'o')
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I'm looking for an SQL sequence that I can run to update everything in the database.

Comment: All right. Check it now.

Comment: I just tried a similar method. The problem is, under the wp_postmeta table you have all other sorts of content that should not have their characters replaced (such as custom field text content), I only want to target image links. You know a way of doing that? Edit: or target any files for that matter.

Comment: Solved it! See updated post.